# Parse output in order delete appropriate files

Tags: powershell

The following script is tasked with deleting older versions of drivers located in Windows' DriverRepository.  It has been amended to filter for drivers by a specific vendor: Konica Minolta.

I want to delete all the Konica Minolta drivers, regardless of whether they are old or not, and this is where I am having difficulties. The script to returns three Konica printer drivers but then the script goes through checks to see whether they are old/dupes etc. which is not required.  I just need to delete whatever is returned initially by the filter e.g. all Konica drivers.

```
$dismOut = Dism /Online /Get-Drivers
$Lines = $dismOut | select -Skip 10  #Discard the first ten lines
$Operation = "theName"
$Drivers = @()

foreach ( $Line in $Lines ) {
    $tmp = $Line
    $txt = $($tmp.Split( ':' ))[1]

    switch ($Operation) {

        'theName' { $Name = $txt
                    $Operation = 'theFileName'
                    break
                  }

        'theFileName' { $FileName = $txt.Trim()
                        $Operation = 'theInbox'
                        break
                      }


        'theInbox' { $Inbox = $txt.Trim()
                    $Operation = 'theClassName'
                    break
                  }

        'theClassName' { $ClassName = $txt.Trim()
                         $Operation = 'theVendor'
                         break
                       }

        'theVendor' { $Vendor = $txt.Trim()
                      $Operation = 'theDate'
                      break
                    }

        'theDate' { # change the date format for easy sorting

                     $tmp = $txt.split( '.' )
                     $txt = "$($tmp[2]).$($tmp[1]).$($tmp[0].Trim())"
                     $Date = $txt
                     $Operation = 'theVersion'
                     break
                   }

        'theVersion' { $Version = $txt.Trim()
                       $Operation = 'theNull'
                       $params = [ordered]@{ 'FileName' = $FileName
                                             'Vendor' = $Vendor
                                             'Date' = $Date
                                             'Name' = $Name
                                             'ClassName' = $ClassName
                                             'Version' = $Version
                                             'Inbox' = $Inbox
                                           }


                        $obj = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $params
                        $Drivers += $obj
                        break
                      }

         'theNull' { $Operation = 'theName'
                    break
                   }

    }

}


Write-Host "ALL INSTALLATION THIRD-PARTY DRIVERS"

$Drivers | sort Filename | where Vendor -eq "KONICA MINOLTA" | ft

Write-Host "Different Versions:"

$last = ''

$NotUnique = @()

foreach ( $Dr in $($Drivers | sort Filename | where Vendor -eq "KONICA MINOLTA") ) {

    if ($Dr.FileName -eq $last  ) {  $NotUnique += $Dr  }

    $last = $Dr.FileName

}

$NotUnique | sort FileName | where Vendor -eq "KONICA MINOLTA" | ft



Write-Host "Outdated Drivers:"

$list = $NotUnique | select -ExpandProperty FileName -Unique

$ToDel = @()

foreach ( $Dr in $list ) {

    Write-Host "Duplicate found..." -ForegroundColor Yellow

    $sel = $Drivers | where { $_.FileName -eq $Dr } | sort date -Descending | select -Skip 1

    $sel | ft

    $ToDel += $sel

}

Write-Host "DRIVERS TO REMOVE:" -ForegroundColor Red

$ToDel | ft

# removing old drivers

foreach ( $item in $ToDel ) {

    $Name = $($item.Name).Trim()

    Write-Host "deleting $Name" -ForegroundColor Yellow

    Write-Host "pnputil.exe -d $Name" -ForegroundColor Yellow

   # Invoke-Expression -Command "pnputil.exe -d $Name"

}
```

I have commented out the line at the bottom that actually performs the deletion so nothing is actually removed.

Answer (score 0):

To delete the driver, you'd need to call DISM again with something like...

```
pnputil /delete-driver <driver>
```

This line here returns the Konica drivers...

```
$Drivers | sort Filename | where Vendor -eq "KONICA MINOLTA" | ft
```

You can adjust that line to get what you want...

```
foreach ($driver in $($Drivers | where Vendor -eq "KONICA MINOLTA")) {
    pnputil /delete-driver $Driver[0].FileName
}
```

You might have to play with the call to pnputil; [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/pnputil-examples) might help. I couldn't test this.

Also, there is a native Powershell DISM module; see [here](https://www.petri.com/getting-started-with-dism-powershell-cmdlets) for details. With that you can call the `Get-WindowsDriver` and `Remove-WindowsDriver` cmdlets. If pnpUtil or dsim don't do what you want, you might want to give them a look.

Comment: Hi @Adam, unfortunately the command DISM.exe /Remove-Driver parameter can only be run on an offline image. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-driver-servicing-command-line-options-s14

Comment: I have since, basically just commented out all everything after    `$Drivers | sort Filename | where Vendor -eq "KONICA MINOLTA" | ft` and changed the bottom 7 lines to the following and it seems to work great now. `#foreach ( $item in $ToDel ) {
foreach ( $item in $Drivers | where Vendor -eq "KONICA MINOLTA" ) {
    $Name = $($item.Name).Trim()
    Write-Host "deleting $Name" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    Write-Host "pnputil.exe -d $Name" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    #Invoke-Expression -Command "pnputil.exe -d $Name"
  }`

Comment: Did the Powershell DISM module look helpful? If not that, on Windows 10, you can find the `pnputil` utility. Whatever approach you use (Posh DISM vs. pnputil), the loop piece would be the same.